# What are typical resonant frequency ranges of large crystals?

Tags: crystals, resonance, piezoelectric

I want to measure the resonant frequency of a crystal about 1 inch long using a transducer and a contact mic. What frequency ranges should I select to be able to measure a variety of different crystals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resonances will be in the ultrasonic range. You will need a transducer which can measure frequencies in the range of ~10 to ~100 kilohertz or more. Common contact mics and audio amps will not do the job; you will need an *ultrasonic transducer* plugged into an *oscilloscope*.